# Large matrix multiplication on gpu

Tags: cuda, gpu, gpgpu, matrix-multiplication

I need to implement a matrix multiplication on GPU with CUDA for large matrices. Size of each matrix alone is bigger than the GPU memory. So I think I need an algorithm to do that efficiently. I went around the internet but couldn't find any. Can anyone give me the name or link of such algorithms.

Comment: What about simply split the matrices like `[A0;A1] * [B0 B1] = [A0*B0 A0*B1; A1*B0 A1*B1]`? That maybe a good start.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There isn't really a formal algorithm for this; in general, these sorts of linear algebra operations where the whole problem isn't stored in memory simultaneously are referred to as "out of core" operations.

To solve it, you don't need a particularly elaborate algorithm, just the CUBLAS library and a pencil and paper. For example, you can decompose the matrix product like this:

[image]

which gives you four independent sub-matrix multiplication operations. These can be calculated using four calls to CUBLAS gemm using very straightforward host code. You can extend the idea to as many sub-matrices as are required to match the problem size and your GPU capacity. The same principle can also be used to implement matrix multiplication problems on multiple GPUs (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11501537/681865) for an example).

In the alternative, you can find a working implementation of this precise idea in the Harvard developed [SciGPU-GEMM](http://code.google.com/p/scigpugemm/) codebase and in the [HPL-CUDA](https://github.com/avidday/hpl-cuda) linpack implementation (disclaimer: I am affiliated with the latter codebase).

Comment: +1. Where did the decomposition came from? Great answer of course!

Comment: @Rekin: I don't understand what you are asking. The mathematics for it came from my head and the image you see was rendered in LaTeX to a gif by me and uploaded to the SO image hosting service.

Comment: Sorry, I was refering to the math formula. I took an algebra class some time ago and the big matrix multiply topic was presented as one of the most problematic to solve computationally. It left me with the false feeling it wasn't possible.

Comment: @Rekin in linear algebra block matrix algorithms are a central topic for efficient numerical implementation. See [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BlockMatrix.html) and how block matrix computations are organized inside [lapack](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/)

Comment: Thank you for the response. I didn't know this matrix property, and it can be a huge issue to not know this!

Comment: This is an old, tried and true technique in HPC. It is sometimes called "strip mining", because the added loop levels and indentations make a loop nest that looks like a strip mine.