# Using cuBLAS-XT for large input size

Tags: cuda, cublas

[This link](https://developer.nvidia.com/cublas)
 says cuBLAS-XT routines provide out-of-core operation – the size of operand data is only limited by system memory size, not by GPU on-board memory size. This means that as long as input data can be stored on CPU memory and size of output is greater than GPU memory size we can use cuBLAS-XT functions, right?

On the other hand, [this link](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/#hybrid_computation) says "In the case of very large problems, the cublasXt API offers the possibility to offload some of the computation to the Host CPU" and "Currenty, only the routine cublasXtgemm() supports this feature. Is this the case for problems that input size is greater than CPU memory size?

I don't get the difference between these two! I appreciate if someone helps me to understand the difference.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14558198/681865

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The purpose of cublasXt is to allow operations to be automatically run on several GPUs.  So, for example, a matrix multiply, or other supported operations, can run on several GPUs.

The cublasXtgemm routine has a *special* capability, that in addition to parallelizing a matrix multiply across 2 or more GPUs, it can also parallelize it across 2 or more GPUs **PLUS** use the host CPU as an additional computation engine.

The matrix multiply problem is readily decomposable as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14558198/681865).  If you run all the "chunks" of work on just GPUs, that is the ordinary capability of cublasXtgemm (to just use GPUs).  If you run all but one of the chunks of work on the GPUs and run one of the chunks of work on the CPU, that is the *special* capability.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'm working with only one GPU and I'm interested in using cublasXT based on what the first link says "the size of operand data is only limited by system memory size, not by GPU on-board memory size". So my question is if I want to use other function like cublasXtSsyrk (which input size is nxk and output size in nxn), and if output size (nxn) is greater than GPU memory size, can I use cublasXtSsyrk?

Comment: I believe you should be able to.  As stated [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html#using-the-cublasXt-api): "The cublasXt API of cuBLAS exposes a multi-GPU capable Host interface : when using this API the application only needs to allocate the required matrices on the Host memory space. **There are no restriction on the sizes of the matrices as long as they can fit into the Host memory.**"