# How to handle large batched multiplication in array fire

Tags: gpu, arrayfire

i'm new to arrayfire and i'm currently having some problems.  I'm currently doing a large batch of matrix multiplications like something below but I run out of memory. Could someone show me an example code to deal with this issue?

```
    int n = 60;
    int m = 18000;
    int k = 600;
    int t = 200;            
    af::array A = randu(m, k, t); 
    af::array B = randu(k, n);   
    af::array C = af::constant(0, m, n, t); 
    C = matmul(A, B);
```

Comment: The first array alone contains 18000*600*200 = 2.16 billion elements = 8.64 Gb of memory. Does your GPU really have 10Gb of free memory?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Its a 2080ti so it does, but I only used this as an example of the problem size. Given the number of matrices i'll need to be using i'll need 4x that anyway. Could you show me an efficient way to transfer memory between host and device for arrayfire for this use case?

Comment: No I can't sorry. I don't use arrayfire on principle

Comment: oh, then could you recommend a way to execute this on a gpu? It doesn't need to be arrayfire it just seemed the easiest way

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14558198/681865