# Efficient algorithm for GEMM in memory limited scenarios

Tags: algorithm, cuda, gpu, matrix-multiplication, cublas

I am looking for an efficient algorithm to perform (dense) large matrix multiplications on GPUs. More specifically, for the case where the GPU does not have enough memory to hold all the matrices (e.g., m=n=k=100,000). I'm using cuBLAS to perform matrix multiplication in blocks, and I can think of many block-based approaches, but they are very inefficient because the A, B or C matrices have to be copied to/from the GPU multiple times.

I know that many efficient algorithms have been proposed (for example, [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00607-020-00846-1)), but I was unable to find a concrete definition of the algorithm used. Is there an algorithm to perform this task without redundant copies (this is, copying A, B and C exactly once)? Any pointers to competitive approaches?

Comment: cublasXt can do this for you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14557067/681865

Answer (score 3):

Such an algorithm is called an [out-of-core algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_memory_algorithm) and this problem is generally solved by using **tiles**. The idea is to first split `A` and `B` in relatively big tiles. Then, send 2 tiles on the GPU, perform the multiplication of the two, write the result in a preallocated tile (always the same), send it back to the CPU and accumulate the result in a tile of the `C` matrix. Actually, this algorithm is the same than the ones used to solve the matrix multiplication except that items are tiles and you need to care about sending/receiving data to/from the GPU. CUDA streams can be used to improve the execution time by overlapping communications with computations. Note that tiles needs to be copied multiple times because you do not have enough memory on the GPU. [Lebesgue curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-order_curve) (aka Z-tiling or Z-order curves) can be used to reduce the number of copies/communications. Doing all of this is a bit complex. Some runtime systems and tools can help you to hide memory transfers more easily (eg. [StarPu](https://team.inria.fr/storm/software/starpu/) which is a research project).